# Trouble with the output of a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a piece of code that proves that two anonymized columns do not show the same information. My original hypothesis was that where `A4`== 'u' that `A5` would then equal 'g'.

After running this for loop, the output gave me heaps of pairs of other variables i.e. 'u' paired with 'p' or 'gg' (these are other values for `A5`:

```
for row4 in crx_data['A4']:
    for row5 in crx_data['A5']:
        if ((row4 == 'u') & (row5 != 'g')):
            print(row4, row5)
```

So therefore I've disproved my hypothesis, but I want to be able to better show this in my work. At the moment this for loop prints tonnes of pairs of these variables that  contradict the 'u'=='g' pattern.

How can I modify my for loop to show these just as many times as they actually appear so that I can count the values to disprove my hypothesis?

Comment: You should use the keyword `and` for your logical conditions. `&` is the "bitwise and" operator

Comment: Dont loop trough a dataframe unless absolutely necessary

Comment: @IainShelvington Not in Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*IIUC: You can use `np.where` to generate the mask to filter the columns where `A4` is `u` and `A5` is other than `g`.
You can use this:*

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.where((crx_data["A4"] == "u") & (crx_data["A5"] != "g"), True, False)
result = crx_data[["A4", "A5"]][mask]
print(result)
print("Number of times such pairs appear:", len(result))
```

OR,

```
result = crx_data[["A4", "A5"]][(crx_data["A4"] == "u") & (crx_data["A5"] != "g")]
print(result)
print("Number of times such pairs appear:", len(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives the count of times 'u' and 'g' were together and count of other case also

```
count_together = 0
count_not_together = 0
for row4 in crx_data['A4']:
    for row5 in crx_data['A5']:
        if ((row4 == 'u') and (row5 == 'g')):
            count_together = count_together + 1
        else:
            count_not_together = count_not_together + 1
print('Count together : ',str(count_together))
print('Count not together : ',str(count_not_together))
```

In your code, you have used bitwise operator '&' instead of keyword 'and'.
https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators